# fatal python error pygame parachute

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

I have written a small program in WindowsXP-python-pygame. It runs fine when I run it in the dos.
Then, I tried to create a windows executable using py2exe. .exe was created without any issue. Initially on running the executable, I got a NotImplemented error which went away after I copied some dll files from pygame folder to the dist folder.
Now I am getting a new error. It reads: 
*"Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."*

I have already looked at the following pages:
[1] http://pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe
[2] http://thadeusb.com/weblog/2009/4/15/pygame_font_and_py2exe
[3] http://www.google.com

These do not seem to be of help. I mean I am getting the error in spite of using all the instructions there. Any idea?

Comment: Alright, I got it working. 

Edited the line "extra_data" in the following place:
http://pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe

to:

self.extra_datas = ["freesansbold.ttf", "SDL.dll", "SDL_ttf.dll", "libfreetype-6.dll", "zlib1.dll"].

This works!

Comment: Neeraj: answer your own question (with the answer box, not a comment), and after 2 days you can accept the answer.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: I cannot answer it yet. 2 more hours before SOF allows me to answer it.

Comment: ah, OK. didn't realize there was also a time delay on answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Edited the line `extra_data` in the following place:

```
pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe
```

to:

```
self.extra_datas = ["freesansbold.ttf",
                    "SDL.dll",
                    "SDL_ttf.dll",
                    "libfreetype-6.dll",
                    "zlib1.dll"]
```

This works!